# How to charge a camera from a car's auxiliary power outlet?

Tags: battery, charger

I have a Canon 50d that I am taking on a camping trip in several weeks. I was wondering if it is possible to charge the battery from a car's auxiliary power outlet. What would I need to do this, if it is indeed possible?

Comment: You need a power inverter. DC to AC. Then you can plug in your battery charger. That is it. Any $30 inverter from your local store will achieve this simple task.

Comment: SOEM LiIon stand alone chargers have 12 VDC in\put and use a mains to 12v power pack to operate them. These can be operated from 12 VDC from a car by inputting it at the 12V input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can buy dedicated accessories for charging all kinds of stuff, or you can spend a little more and get a car converter 12V -> 110V, or 220V, depending on what your chargers need.

Then you can connect just about any standard device to it, as long as its current (wattage) requirements are not too high.

Here is [one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003Q54V88) similar to one I have and it came in handy many times - most notably when camping:

Comment: This is exactly what I do, I have a power inverter in the back of my Honda Element and it charges my batteries as I drive from place to place.

Answer (score 6):

If you want an official Canon accessory, you can use the CB-570 Car Battery Cable.  It works with the CG-570 Battery Charger and is listed on the accessories page for the 50d.

As others mentioned, a power inverter is also a more general solution, though converting from DC to AC back to DC will use additional power and put additional strain on your alternator.  It's not a big deal, but it is worth noting since it will have a larger impact on millage (though still likely insignificant overall.)

It becomes a question of if you want a direct and efficient solution or a more generally useful device that can be used for multiple needs.

Comment: This is a little pricier than a standard 110/120V adapter although perhaps slightly more compact. Not usable for anything else though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  Buy a camera charger with car adapter with it.  it's around $10 at [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0023W2S9O).

Answer (score 0):

SOME LiIon stand alone chargers have 12 VDC input. Some have a car cord only (supplied). Others use a mains to 12v power pack to operate them. These can be operated from 12 VDC from a car by inputting it at the 12V input.

A number [here on ebay](http://www.ebay.com.au/bhp/canon-50d-charger) from about $US5.

[12V with auto cigarette lighter plug and cord](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/BATTERY-CHARGER-FOR-BP-511-511A-512-CANON-EOS-40D-50D-/180900499686) ebay $5.43. NJ source allegedly.

About $US13. Posts from Hong Kong. MAY have mains and car inputs. Read ad carefully, as ever
[ebay Battery charger for Canon BP-511 EOS 50D 40D 30D 60 G6](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Battery-charger-for-Canon-BP-511-EOS-50D-40D-30D-60-G6-/110589703421)